Next.js with Dockerfile build stopped working 18th July 2024 on Google Cloud Run with error: 91msh: next: not found
I have a Next.js application that I have build many times on Google Cloud Run. It uses a Dockerfile to build. Suddenly yesterday it stopped building and I have no idea why.
I tried to create a completely new app and deploy it, but I got the same error.
npx create-next-app@latest my-next-app

Build logs from Google Cloud Run
Step #0 - "Build": [0m
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
ERROR
Finished Step #0 - "Build"
Step #0 - "Build": The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 127
Step #0 - "Build": [91msh: next: not found
Step #0 - "Build": 
Step #0 - "Build": > next build
Step #0 - "Build": > myapp24@0.1.0 build
Step #0 - "Build": 
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 91d8508fbdd5
Step #0 - "Build": Step 11/23 : RUN npm run build
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 71a18abb6942
Step #0 - "Build": Step 10/23 : COPY . .
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> b11b9a99d7a9
Step #0 - "Build": Step 9/23 : COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 4f5181f1bedd
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container b0e99f9a70b3
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in b0e99f9a70b3
Step #0 - "Build": Step 8/23 : WORKDIR /app
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 6025c1b71365
Step #0 - "Build": Step 7/23 : FROM base AS builder
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 46a13a51ed5f
Step #0 - "Build": [0mRemoving intermediate container 2408ef28b7ea
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-19T16_12_18_353Z-debug-0.log
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm error   <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm error Exit handler never called!
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
Step #0 - "Build": [0m[91mnpm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
Step #0 - "Build": [91mnpm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 2408ef28b7ea
Step #0 - "Build": Step 6/23 : RUN npm ci
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 4e6fb925cc3d
Step #0 - "Build": Step 5/23 : COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 150e95a5cd86
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container b38fd952f67d
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in b38fd952f67d
Step #0 - "Build": Step 4/23 : WORKDIR /app
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 9159ccd1311f
Step #0 - "Build": Removing intermediate container 29cbbc5d6af9
Step #0 - "Build": OK: 11 MiB in 19 packages
Step #0 - "Build": (3/3) Installing gcompat (1.1.0-r4)
Step #0 - "Build": (2/3) Installing libucontext (1.2-r3)
Step #0 - "Build": (1/3) Installing musl-obstack (1.2.3-r2)
Step #0 - "Build": fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Step #0 - "Build": fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> Running in 29cbbc5d6af9
Step #0 - "Build": Step 3/23 : RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 6025c1b71365
Step #0 - "Build": Step 2/23 : FROM base AS deps
Step #0 - "Build":  ---> 6025c1b71365
Step #0 - "Build": Status: Downloaded newer image for node:alpine
Step #0 - "Build": Digest: sha256:fefab66d0b14d21646eda6ac130343ec01419bbc92bfc0669790ce2ee57641bd
Step #0 - "Build": c35758af0749: Pull complete
Step #0 - "Build": 8be926ce2f4f: Pull complete
Step #0 - "Build": 0efaaed94ccc: Pull complete
Step #0 - "Build": 0efaaed94ccc: Download complete
Step #0 - "Build": 0efaaed94ccc: Verifying Checksum
Step #0 - "Build": 8be926ce2f4f: Download complete
Step #0 - "Build": 8be926ce2f4f: Verifying Checksum
Step #0 - "Build": c35758af0749: Download complete
Step #0 - "Build": c35758af0749: Pulling fs layer
Step #0 - "Build": 8be926ce2f4f: Pulling fs layer
Step #0 - "Build": 0efaaed94ccc: Pulling fs layer
Step #0 - "Build": ec99f8b99825: Already exists
Step #0 - "Build": alpine: Pulling from library/node
Step #0 - "Build": Step 1/23 : FROM node:alpine AS base
"Step #0 - ""Build"": Sending build context to Docker daemon  382.5kB

"
Step #0 - "Build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Starting Step #0 - "Build"
BUILD
HEAD is now at 89c4f2f Dockerfile
 * branch            89c4f2f60a5f3da9aafb7dfa835c22c6dedf2ed5 -> FETCH_HEAD
From https://github.com/myrepo/myapp24
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
"hint:  git branch -m <name>"
hint:
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint:
"hint:  git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>"
hint:
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
FETCHSOURCE
"starting build ""0c619e6e-882a-4cb5-89bd-33663c2a35f5""
"

Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine AS base

# 2) Install dependencies only when needed.
FROM base AS deps

# 3) Install packages with no cache
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

# 4) Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm update && npm install


# 5) Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# 6) Build the code
RUN npm run build

# 7) Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# 8) Set the correct permission for prerender cache.
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# 9) Reduce the Image size
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# 10) Expose the port
USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# 11) server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "standalone"
};

export default nextConfig;

What have changed so that my app will not build any more?
